# powershell, find a date string

Tags: powershell

Apologies for the bad scripting but im a begginer in scripting. Got to start somewhere.

I wish to create a script that looks for a file that has yesterdays date in so is always Day-1 eg today is the 20180824 but I wish to check for 20180823

```
$file = "test{0}.txt" -f (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)ToString("yyyyMMdd") 
Test-Path C:\temp\$file -PathType Leaf'
```

Any ideas what is wrong with this script please

Comment: you forgot a `.` before the `ToString()` method. Other than that, your script seems to work just fine

Comment: There's a trailing `'` also but I assume that was just a type in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Changes Made added `.ToString()` and  removed trailing `'`

> $file = "test{0}.txt" -f (Get-Date).AddDays(-1).ToString("yyyyMMdd")
>
> Test-Path C:\temp\$file -PathType Leaf

[image: PowerShell Syntax Correction]

Hope This Helps !!

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, you've got a missing period:

```
$file = "test{0}.txt" -f (Get-Date).AddDays(-1).ToString("yyyyMMdd")
```

You can also specify the format in the placeholder itself:

```
$file = "test{0:yyyyMMdd}.txt" -f (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)
```